# Cross matrix values in R

Tags: r

Consider I have a list of products : For example 100 product names 
              Product$list
                  A
                  B
                  C

I want 100 * 100 combination in Product$list1 and Product$list2
   Example:3*3 = 9 combinations

```
         Product$list1       Product$list2
              A                   B
              A                   C
              B                   A
              B                   C
              C                   A
              C                   B
              A                   A
              B                   B
              C                   C
```

Can somebody help me how to achieve this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `combn`

```
 setNames(as.data.frame(t(combn(Product$Col,2))), paste0("Col",1:2))
```

#### data

```
Product <- data.frame(Col=LETTERS[1:3], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: solution <- t(combn(LETTERS[1:3], 2))
    print(solution)

Comment: @Nemo Yes, that was what I earlier posted.  Changed it so that if the OP's data is something else, it could still be used.

Comment: oh, I did not know that ! however, you are always two steps in front of me :-D